# How specific should I be in my SOP, regarding courses and thesis subject?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, statement-of-purpose

I know there isn't an absolute answer but I certainly could use some hindsight.
I'm writing an SOP for an Msc at TU Delft in Aerospace, and I am having trouble with two parts of it : specifically I'm required to provide hypothetical thesis topics and explain why among the different tracks in Aerospace I want one in particular.

First of all, regarding the track, I've explain my interest by explaining in detail which courses I'm really eager to follow and which part of these courses I feel are the most appealing, but I'm not sure if I should be this is the right approach, I'm also wondering if I' not going too much in details by being so specific about the courses.

Then about the thesis subject, I know what the focus of the Msc is going to be , what courses I will follow and what the research themes are but I don't know what thesis subject are going to look like, and what is a relevant subject or not. So I don't know if I should stay a bit generic and talk about the fields of research or try to make a concrete thesis subject anyway ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For thesis topics, I would recommend you to have a look at the website of the university. Often, finished as well as open theses are listed there. You can use this as a starting point for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The expected Statement of Purpose probably differs between fields, countries and even institutions. In economics, it is not a major factor in admissions even if required. People write about their general interest area and proposed topic, with the expectation that their actual thesis may be completely different.

As I understand it, the purpose of the SOP is just to demonstrate having an idea about the field in general and being able to distinguish subfields. As mentioned, this may vary across fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can only give a little bit of hindsight from my own personal experience and it may also vary a lot depending on the universities. But in my case, I didn't go in depth, and stayed very superficial overall, mostly referring to the subjects that the documents and information that the university provides and in the end it was enough.

But then again it isn't really representative, only somebody who actually evaluated applications may be able to provide objective answers.